Troubleshooting Slideshow Image Sizing and Navigation Dot Alignment Issues in CSS


/*Main Styles*/
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

html, a {
    font-family: "Francois One", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    color: rgb(43, 65, 98);
    text-decoration: none;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 20px;
}

main header {
    padding: 20px;
}

.title {
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-image: url('images/fulls/08.jpg');
    background-size: cover;    
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}

.title h2 {
    color: white;
    font-size: 3rem;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-top: 25%;
}

.intro {         
    background-color: rgb(43, 65, 98);
    color: white;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 50%;
}

.intro p {
    font-size: 2rem;
    margin: 2%;
    width: 100%;
}

.content {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

/* Sidebar Styles */
#hamburger {
    margin: 1rem 1rem 0 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

i.icons {
    margin-right: 1rem;
}

#sidebar {
    width: 0px;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgb(247, 247, 247);
    z-index: 2; 
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: width .5s ease;
    white-space: nowrap; 
}

#hamburger, #sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}

#sidebar ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

#sidebar a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

#sidebar li {
    line-height: 2rem;
}

.address, .major {
    padding-left: 1.5rem;
}

.major {
    padding: 3rem 0 3rem 1.5rem;
}

ul.nav {
    padding-left: 5rem;
    padding-bottom: 5rem;
}

.contact {
    padding-left: 3rem;
}

section .major {
    border-top: 2px dotted rgb(244, 209, 174);
}

#sidebar section {
    padding-top: 5rem;
}

#sidebar a:hover {
    background-color: rgb(244, 209, 174);
}

#overlay {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    display: none;
}

/* Slideshow Styles */
.slideshow {
    width: 50%;
    height: 55vh;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: rgb(43, 65, 98);
}

.slideshow img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    object-fit: cover;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.slideshow img:first-child {
    z-index: 1;
}

.navigation-button {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.dot-container {
    width: 90%;
    text-align: center;
}

.dot {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    margin: 0 2px;
    background-color: rgb(187, 187, 187);
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
    background-color: rgb(113, 113, 113);
}

/* Media Queries for Responsive Adjustments */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .title h2 {
        font-size: 2.5rem;
        padding-left: 20px;
    }

    .intro, .slideshow {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .intro p {
        font-size: 1.5rem;
    }
}
            <nav class="menu">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-bars fa-2x " id="hamburger"></i>

                <div id="overlay"></div>
                <div id="sidebar">
                    <header class="major">
                        <h2>Menu</h2>
                    </header>
                    
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li><a href="#">Homepage</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li> 
                    </ul>

                    <section>
                        <header class="major">
                            <h2>Get in touch</h2>
                        </header>
                        <ul class="contact">
                            <li><i class="icons fa-brands fa-instagram fa-xl" style="color: #f1bd86;"></i><a href="#">Instagram</a></li>
                            <li><i class="icons fa-regular fa-envelope fa-lg" style="color: #f1bd86;"></i>info@untitles.com</li>
                            <li><i class="icons fa-solid fa-phone fa-lg" style="color: #f1bd86;"></i>(000) 000-000</li>
                            <li> <i class="icons fa-solid fa-map-pin fa-lg" style="color: #f1bd86;"></i>1234 Somewhere</li>
                            <li class="address"> Los Angeles, CA 0000</li>
                        </ul>
                    </section>
                </div>
            </nav>

            <main>
                <header>
                    <h1><a href="index.html">Chef Kavy's Kitchen</a></h1>
                </header>

                <section class="title">
                    <h2>LA's Premier Chef & Caterer</h2>
                </section>

                <section class="content">
                    <section class="intro">
                        <p>
                            Welcome to Chef Kavy's Kitchen, where each dish is a celebration of flavor and each event is a showcase of culinary mastery.
                        </p> 
                        <p>
                            Chef Kavy has not only catered to stars like Nipsey Hussle, Snoop Dogg, Wiz Khalifa, Niecy Nash, Brandy, and H.E.R., but he has also brought his exceptional culinary skills to a variety of settings, from intimate dinners to large-scale events.
                        </p>
                    </section>

                    <div class="slideshow">
                        <img src="images/fulls/01.jpg" alt="img1">
                        <img src="images/fulls/02.jpg" alt="img2">
                        <img src="images/fulls/03.jpg" alt="img3">
                        <img src="images/fulls/04.jpg" alt="img4">
                        <img src="images/fulls/05.jpg" alt="img5">
                        <img src="images/fulls/06.jpg" alt="img6">
                        <img src="images/fulls/07.jpg" alt="img7">
                        <img src="images/fulls/09.jpg" alt="img8">
                        <img src="images/fulls/10.jpg" alt="img9">
                        <img src="images/fulls/11.jpg" alt="img10">
                        <img src="images/fulls/12.jpg" alt="img11">
                    
                    <div class="dot-container">
                        <div class="navigation-button">
                            <span class="dot active" onclick="changeSlide(0)"></span>
                            <span class="dot" onclick="changeSlide(1)"></span>
                            <span class="dot" onclick="changeSlide(2)"></span>
                            <span class="dot" onclick="changeSlide(3)"></span>
                            <span class="dot" onclick="changeSlide(4)"></span>
                            <span class="dot" onclick="changeSlide(5)"></span>
                            <span class="dot" onclick="changeSlide(6)"></span>
                            <span class="dot" onclick="changeSlide(7)"></span>
                            <span class="dot" onclick="changeSlide(8)"></span>
                            <span class="dot" onclick="changeSlide(9)"></span>
                            <span class="dot" onclick="changeSlide(10)"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>      
                </div>
            
                
                </section>

            </main>
    
  



I'm very new to web development and am working on a web project that includes a slideshow component. I'm encountering two main issues:

Slideshow Image Sizing: My slideshow images are not sizing properly. Depending on the screen size, they either appear too small or overflow from their container. I want the images to fill the container without being cropped or overflowing, and they should adjust responsively to different screen sizes.

Navigation Dot Alignment: Additionally, the navigation dots, which are supposed to align directly below the slideshow images, are not positioning themselves correctly. They either overlap with the images or are too far from them.


Adjusting the height of .slideshow to vh or percentages does not consistently line up with the adjacent .intro section. Changing these dimensions either causes the images to overflow or be too small.
I've attempted several adjustments in the heights and alignments but none align the navigation dots properly below the images without issues.
Could anyone provide insight on how to fix these issues to ensure the images resize properly within the container and the navigation dots are aligned correctly below the images? Any suggestions to synchronize the alignment with the .intro section would also be greatly appreciated.

If you want to design a slider then use one of the slider owl-carousel or swiper slider, you can easily achieve what you need.
